# Buscar menor inteiro disponível no MySQL

Tags: mysql

Gostaria de saber se há a possibilidade de criar uma *query* que retorne o menor inteiro disponível. É um pouco complicado de explicar, mas com um exemplo facilita:

```
id | codigo
---|-------
 1 | 1
 2 | 2
 3 | 4
 4 | 5
 5 | 6
```

Nesse caso, gostaria que a *query* retornasse o número 3, pois é o menor inteiro que ainda está disponível. E se um registro fosse inserido contendo o código 3, retornasse o número 7, pois este passaria a ser o menor inteiro disponível.

Comment: Independentemente das informações... Eu só gostaria de uma query que retornasse, nesse caso, o número 3, pois ele é o próximo da ordem que foi pulado. Por exemplo, no banco tenho 5 registros, com os seguintes códigos: 1,2,3,6,7. Nesse caso, gostaria de uma consulta q retornasse o número 4.

Answer (score 2):

Se considerarmos a seguinte tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `code` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Com os seguintes registros:

```
+----+-----------+------+
| id | name      | code |
+----+-----------+------+
| 1  | produto 1 | 1    |
+----+-----------+------+
| 2  | produto 2 | 2    |
+----+-----------+------+
| 3  | produto 3 | 4    |
+----+-----------+------+
| 4  | produto 4 | 6    |
+----+-----------+------+
```

Ou seja, o menor código disponível será o 3. Para obtê-lo, fazemos:

```
SELECT min(products.code + 1) AS code FROM products
LEFT JOIN products AS temp ON products.code + 1 = temp.code
WHERE temp.code IS NULL;
```

Ou seja, selecione o menor valor do código incrementado em 1 de um produto que não possui um produto com código cadastrado adjacente ao mesmo. Por exemplo, sem utilizar a função `min`, os valores retornados seriam 3, 5, 7, pois o produto de código 2 não possui um produto adjacente em 3, o produto de código 4 não possui adjacente em 5 e o produto de código 6 não possui um produto em 7. Como o valor retornado é incrementado em 1, seria 2+1, 4+1, 6+1. Utilizando a função `min`, retornamos apenas o menor deles: 3.

```
| code |
|------|
|    3 |
```

> Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f17d14/1/0).

Se um registro for adicionado com o código 3:

```
+----+-----------+------+
| id | name      | code |
+----+-----------+------+
| 1  | produto 1 | 1    |
+----+-----------+------+
| 2  | produto 2 | 2    |
+----+-----------+------+
| 3  | produto 3 | 4    |
+----+-----------+------+
| 4  | produto 4 | 6    |
+----+-----------+------+
| 5  | produto 5 | 3    | 
+----+-----------+------+
```

O resultado da mesma consulta será:

```
| code |
|------|
|    5 |
```

> Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e370/1/0).

Comment: Anderson, obrigado! Já ajudou bastante, porém dessa forma não funcionaria caso o produto 1 não existisse, correto? Teria alguma forma de adaptar?

Comment: No caso, eu gostaria que o código 1 retornasse, caso o mesmo não existisse.

Comment: De fato não havia testado esta possibilidade. E se inverter a lógica verificando o registro anterior, utilizando -1 ao invés de +1? Não tenho como testar agora, mas acho que funcionaria, retornando vazio se não houverem espaços disponíveis, podendo fazer o insert diretamente mesmo.